# Classifying images using pre-trained (Tensorflow) CNN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, tf-slim

I have trained alexnet_v2 on my own dataset, and now would like to use it within another application. This should be very simple and I've tried to implement it in a number of ways but either I get errors I can't work around or (in the case of the code below) it hangs indefinitely.

Ideally, I'd like it in C++ (but the C++ API seems unreliable, or at least has outdated documentation in many places, so python is acceptable), and I'd like to be classifying large groups of images (for example: providing the program with 80 images of animals and returning whether any of them show a cat).

Am I going about this the right way with the code below? If so, how can I fix it.

If not, are there any working examples of a better way?

Many thanks.

```
import tensorflow as tf

#Using preprocessing and alexnet_v2 net from the slim examples

from nets import nets_factory
from preprocessing import preprocessing_factory

#Checkpoint file from training on binary dataset

checkpoint_path = '/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/models/slim/data/checkpoint.ckpt'

slim = tf.contrib.slim

number_of_classes = 2


image_filename = '/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/models/slim/data/images/neg_sample_123459.jpg'

image_filename_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.string)

image_tensor = tf.read_file(image_filename_placeholder)

image_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_tensor, channels=3)

image_batch_tensor = tf.expand_dims(image_tensor, axis=0)

#Use slim's alexnet_v2 implementation

network_fn = nets_factory.get_network_fn('alexnet_v2',num_classes=2,is_training=False)

#Use inception preprocessing

preprocessing_name = 'inception'
image_preprocessing_fn= preprocessing_factory.get_preprocessing(preprocessing_name,is_training=False)

image_tensor=image_preprocessing_fn(image_tensor,network_fn.default_image_size,network_fn.default_image_size)

label=3
images,labels=tf.train.batch(
    [image_tensor,label],
    batch_size=2,
    num_threads=1,
    capacity=10)

pred,_=network_fn(images)

initializer = tf.local_variables_initializer()

init_fn=slim.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
    checkpoint_path,
    slim.get_model_variables('alexnet_v2'))

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(initializer)
    init_fn(sess)
    tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)
    image_np, pred_np = sess.run([image_tensor, pred], feed_dict={image_filename_placeholder: image_filename})
```

EDIT: After adding line in bold, the program no longer hangs. However I'm getting a placeholder error:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder' with dtype string [[Node: Placeholder =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_STRING, shape=[],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

I've double checked the spelling, and as far as I can see I'm feeding it correctly. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.train.batch()` function uses background threads to prefetch examples, but you need to add an explicit command ([`tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/start_queue_runners)) to start these threads. Rewriting the last part of your code as follows should stop it hanging:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(initializer)
  init_fn(sess)

  # Starts background threads for input preprocessing.
  tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)

  image_np, pred_np = sess.run(
      [image_tensor, pred],
      feed_dict={image_filename_placeholder: image_filename})
```

Comment: I think the problem is that `image_filename_placeholder` used by the queue runners (which fill up the queue used for batching images by calling `sess.run()` internally), but the queue runners don't know what filename to feed. Looking more closely at your program, if you're classifying one image at a time, you don't need the `tf.train.batch()` at all: you can simply pass the result of `tf.decode_jpeg()` to `network_fn()` (perhaps after reshaping it).

Comment: In the final program I'm intending to be classifying ~80 images in total per call to the network, which is why that's there as I'll need to be passing a batch (I just simplified a little for the original question).